# Should I migrate from my i9 MacBook to my new M1 or should I reinstall from scratch?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

I just got a new M1 MacBook Pro from work. My old one is an i9 MacBook Pro.

Since these two machines run on different chips with different architecture - I was wondering if I should migrate my apps from the old machine to the new or simply reinstall everything.

I think that migrating apps that were compiled to run on Intel arch might be a mistake. It's a bit of a waste to have these run over whatever software layer intended for compatibility.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, I would always want to set up a new device fresh. More so in this case where you have 2 different architectures.

Comment: You can migrate everything but apps, but I agree with your hunch that manually re-installing your apps gives you a better chance of getting Apple silicon binaries installed. Some third-party apps may not be smart enough to upgrade themselves from x86-only to Apple silicon versions when they find themselves running on Apple silicon Macs.